# How can I add a blank editable row with Ant Design table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Trying to create an "Add Row" button that results in a new fillable/editable row added to the table. The issue is, when I have the editable fields be empty strings, the edit field does not display and thus the user cannot change the contents of it:

```
// RESULTS IN NO FIELD DISPLAYED
const newCategoryRow = {
    key: 'NEW',
    acct: '',
    description: '',
    total: 0
}

// RESULTS IN FIELD DISPLAYED
const newCategoryRow = {
    key: 'NEW',
    acct: 'blah',
    description: 'blah',
    total: 0
}
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the empty strings with "-".

Or give an initial value for the editable Cell:

```
    const getInput = (props) => {
        if (props.inputType === 'number')
            return (
                <Input
                    type={'number'}
                    style={{ margin: 0, padding: 4, fontSize: 13 }}
                />);
        //Default field
        else
            return (
                <Input
                    type={'text'}
                    style={{ margin: 0, padding: 5 }}
                />);
    }

            <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                {props.form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, 
                    { initialValue: "-", })(getInput(props))}
            </Form.Item>
```